# Iterate through triple nested tuple Python 3.4

Tags: python, nested, iteration, tuples

Let's say I have a triple nested tuple that I am using to create a keyboard in TKinter. It looks something like this:

```
kBoard = (
( ('~\n`', 1), ('!\n1', 1),..... etc.
 ),
(('Tab', 2), ('Q', 1),.... etc.
 ),
(('CapsLock', 2), ('A', 1),... etc. and so on
 ),
)
```

Let's say I want to iterate through this such that the second layer are rows of the keyboard and I want to grab each definition to use as a key. I tried a nested for loop and that gave me multiple duplicates and didn't really allow me to grab individual definitions. So how would I do this so that I can grab each definition individually? Keep in mind, I am trying to grab these definitions in the order they are in in the tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Itertools.chain`:-

```
dict(itertools.chain(*kBoard))
```

Output:-

```
{'A': 1, '!\n1': 1, 'Q': 1, 'CapsLock': 2, '~\n`': 1, 'Tab': 2}
```

or you may `List Comprehension` with `dict` function,

```
>>>[dict(tup) for tup in kBoard]
```

output:-

```
>>> 
[{'!\n1': 1, '~\n`': 1}, {'Q': 1, 'Tab': 2}, {'A': 1, 'CapsLock': 2}]
```

Or Use simple `map` function:-

```
>>>map(dict, kBoard)

[{'!\n1': 1, '~\n`': 1}, {'Q': 1, 'Tab': 2}, {'A': 1, 'CapsLock': 2}]
```

Comment: You can also make dictionary with `dict(itertools.chain(*kBoard))`